# org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.spi.HibernateException: Could not get list of tables from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am getting below error in Hibernate Tools.

org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.spi.HibernateException: Could not get list of tables from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
Configured schema:null
Configured catalog:null
Available schemas:
Available catalogs:
  fse
  information_schema
  mysql
  performance_schema
  sakila
  sys
  world

```
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:141)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:124)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:64)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:231)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE','VIEW',null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.executeMetadataQuery(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:62)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.getTables(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.TableProcessor.processTables(TableProcessor.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.readDatabaseSchema(AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:132)
    ... 7 more

I am using Eclipse Neon(4.6.2), Downloaded Hibernate-Tools from Jboss, Using Hiberate Tool Version 5.2, Hibernate Version - 5.2.17.Final, MySQL- 8.0.15, Java - 1.8. 
Can anyone provide solution with above configuration?

Comment: Database Dialect showing - MySql and MySql 5 only in Hibernate Tool

Comment: Update Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is showing Hibernate putting a `HAVING` clause before an `ORDER BY`. This is invalid SQL. Based on @LppEdd 's commend I suggest updating Hibernate and hoping its fixed.